# Select first child's children with Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, find, children

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="one">
  <div id="two">
    <h2>Any</h2>
    <h4>Any</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to select the first and the first's children elements, in the above case: #two, h2, h4, without knowing the first element's id name.
How could I do that?

I can select the first element but if I add contents().find() to div:first I can't select its children:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".one").mouseover(function () {  
        $(this).children('div:first').contents().find('h2,h4').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
     });

    $(".one").mouseout(function () { 
        $(this).children('div:first').contents().find('h2,h4').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

The final and working (no flicker!) code is:

```
$(".one").hover(function () {  
$(this).children('div:first').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {;
$(this).children('div:first').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

I guess I have to give myself more time to think before coming here and asking questions. Anyway, I learned about .andSelf() and the a bit of Jquery syntax. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use both `find()` and `contents()` - Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".one").mouseover(function () {  
        $(this).children('div:first').children('h2,h4').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
     });

    $(".one").mouseout(function () { 
        $(this).children('div:first').children('h2,h4').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

And if you need to also keep the 'first' element in the nodeset, use `.andSelf()` after the second `.children()` (as per @Felix 's answer).

Comment: This is actually a little wrong because his code was prone to error. He just wants the children and not the descendants so find('h2,h4') returns the wrong set of elements.

Comment: Actually, for the problem he has it doesn't matter. Nevermind.

Comment: Thanks guys, it appears that I don't have to include h2,h4 to fadein/fadeout the div - my original problem is that hovering over the faded in h2 and h4 elements makes the div flicker.

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`children` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`andSelf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/):

```
$(".one").mouseover(function () {  
    $(this).children().first().children('h2, h4').andSelf()....
});
```

If you don't want to add the first child (the parent) to the set, omit `andSelf`. Your question is a bit vague in this point. But I assume you actually don't want to select the first child, only its children. If you hide an element, its children are hidden too.

Comment: @elbatron: So you want to call `fadeOut` on the children and the element itself? What's the purpose of it? If you hide the parent, the children will be hidden too.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wanted to select both the first element and its children. I had this previously:    '   $(this).children('div:first').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
'    and it is doing the same as your code above at least the result is the same... It looks like it only selects the first element without its children:... although the div fadein and out properly hovering over to the h2 and h4 elements the div flickers... Because of that flicker I thought that I need to include the the first item's children as well in the Jquery...

Comment: @elbatron: Mmmh. Well now you know at least how you can select all of them and you can play around ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. Is there any other way to prevent the flicker? (selecting all or just the first child div result  it)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  $(this).children('div:first').contents().find('h2,h4').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
```

To:

```
  $(this).children('div:first').children('h2,h4').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
```